# Keyset does not exist exception with deployment on windows server 2012 on Azure

Tags: azure, windows-server-2012

I got a problem with upgrading my deployment to windows server 2012, my deploy works fine with osfamily=2 and compiled with .net4, but failed at .net4.5 and osfamily=3,

the exception I saw when remote to the vm is "Keyset does not exist", seems to related to some certificates. My program using the certificates to encrypt some stream and should be able to using this certs to decode this stream after I deploy it.
I checked the certs on vm, it is installed fine, in the right place. 
So I suspect this is an issue with the different secure policy with 2012 that prevent my role to get the key in the certs.

this blocks me for a while so Thank a lot for any clue!

Answer (score 6):

Keyset does not exist typically refers to an error when your program is trying to access a private key of a certificate and is unable to do so, either because the private key does not exist or because it has no permissions to access it

You will need to find the certificate in question in your certificate store, verify that it contains a private key (that will show up in the properties of the certificate)

[image: Certificate properties]

And then verify that your process/application pool has permissions to access the private key by right-clicking on the certificate from the certificate store and choosing: All Tasks->Manage Private Keys.  From there, make sure to add sufficient users to the allowed list

[image: Add permissions]

Hope this helps